# Java reference does not work as a pointer?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

Here is a piece of code in my algorithm:

```
public void insert(int element) {
    _insert(element, root);
    System.out.println(root);
}

private void _insert (int element, Node t) {
    if (t == null) {
        t = new Node(null, element);;
        return;
    }
}
```

`Node` here is a predefined class.

When the public method `insert` is called, the private method will be called and check if the tree is empty. If so, a new node would be created at `root` position.

The output is supposed to be a node. However the actual output is `null` which means root is not updated though it's passed as t into the private method.

This should work under C++ with pointers. Maybe I misunderstand something in Java?

Comment: **Passing a Java reference works *exactly* the same as a C pointer** when it comes to method/function calls (assuming the pointer "is valid"). Do *not* confuse Java references with with C++ references. Please see [Call-By-Object-Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing), which describes this "phenomena" and discusses how it relates to local variables. (Pass-By-Value[-Of-The-Reference] is the Java Implementation.)

Comment: (So, no, the above code *won't* work as-is with C++ pointers, see my other expanded comment. In any case the pointer-of-pointer - C style - can be emulated with a mutable object. I would generally not recommend such side-effects though. :-)

Comment: @pst Yes you're right. I checked my original code in C++ and it was using references not pointers. Good call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java always uses pass-by-value for method calls. When you pass a reference type to a method, a *copy of the reference* is made.

The following line changes `t` to refer to a new object, but it does not change the original variable `root`:

```
t = new Node(null, element);
```

---

You can change your method to return the inserted node, as follows:

```
private Node _insert (int element, Node t) {
    if (t == null) {
        t = new Node(null, element);
    }
    return t;
}
```

And call like this:

```
root = _insert(element, root);
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, there is no way to implement the pointer style (without using return value passing) in Java?

Comment: @NSF: There is no pass-by-reference in Java. It's possible to put a reference inside another object, and mutate that object. But the approach I showed is much simpler and cleaner.

Comment: @pst 'copy of the reference' and 'different variable' are the same thing.

Comment: @pst 'Feels off' and 'bugs me' are not about correctness, they are about your feelings, and the specified semantics of Java are not an 'implementation detail'.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, references are a mix of C++ pointers and references.  Sometimes, they behave like a C++ pointer and some other times, like a C++ reference.  When making an assignation, passed as an argument to a function or used in an equality test, they behave like pointers but when accessing a member, they behave like a C++ reference.  That's it, writing t.x in Java is always interpreted like the equivalent of t->x for a pointer in C/C++ (or t.x for a C++ reference but unlike Java, a C++ reference never behave like a pointer).

Futhermore, in Java and in general object oriented programming, most people will not consider to represent an empty list with a null variable as to be a good idea.  Once initialised, a variable should always reference a fully functional object and therefore, an empty list should be identified by the internal state of the object; not by the use of a null reference. Using the return value of a function to re-assign a node that is itself passed as an argument to the same function is more like some good old fashioned C/C++ hacking then proper modern object oriented design. Therefore, instead of:

```
root = _insert(root, element);
```

you should write something like:

```
MyList root = new MyList();
root._insert (element);
```

and somewhere in your class MyList:

```
private void _insert (int element) { 
  if (this.endNode == null) { 
      this.endNode = new Node(); 
  } else {
      this.endNode.nextNode = new Node();
      this.endNote = this.endNote.nextNode;
  }

  this.endNode.element = element;
}
```

If you want your _insert function to be able to insert an element at an arbitrary position inside the linked list, then you should past the parent of the node (or null for your element to be inserted in the very first position) or use a double linked list.

BTW, Java already has a full set of collections (both generic and non-generic) to represent trees and lists that should be able to covert must basic needs.

Comment: No, they always behave like a C++ pointer. The operators are just different between languages. The `.` operator in Java is exactly the same as the `->` operator in C++. There is no equivalent of the C++ `.` operator in Java because objects are not values in Java.

Comment: Well, if you re-read my first answer, the fact that . operator in Java is the same as the -> operator in C++ and there is no C++ . operator in Java is exactly what I've said and in this regard, they behave like C++ references but when it comes to assignation and comparaison, they behave like pointers; so obviously they don't always behave like a C++ pointer nor a C++ reference but instead are a mix of both.

Comment: "behave" talks about semantics. How the operators are written is not part of the semantics.